# Best practice to build a CD pipeline to deploy application to different environments

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, jenkins, continuous-integration, war

Currently I'm trying to build a CD pipeline for our application, which is a typical `Maven J2EE` project and we'll deploy a war to `Tomcat` container.

Our plan for the CD pipeline looks like this:

```
CI(Run UT and build the WAR) -> Deploy to DEV -> Deploy to SIT -> Deploy UAT -> Deploy PROD
```

To follow the best practices of CD, we only build the binary(war) once in the CI phase, but we have some configuration files which are different for each environment, so what's the best way to put the related configuration files for each environment during the deployment phase?

We're using `Jenkins and the build-pipe-line plugin` to build the `pipeline`, are there any recommended plugins to make this happen?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to use Jenkins I'd recommend you take a look at the [Jenkins workflow plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin), which was designed with complex pipelines and similar tasks in mind.

Comment: @DenizU Thanks, I'll have a look at this plugin :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Configuring the artifact**

- Write a script to replace the config files if they're embedded in the
  WAR.

You may employ maven-antrun-plugin to

1. Extract the WAR
2. Replace the config
3. Repack the WAR

The ant task should be reused for different environments:

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <tasks>
        <echo message="Configuring artifact, ${PIPELINE_STAGE}"/>
        <!-- extracting,replacing,repacking -->
    </tasks>
</configuration?
```

- Externalize the config files. Well, just upload the config files to the server.

**Sharing the artifact through pipeline stages**

1. Upload the WAR to your artifact repository.
2. Dowload the WAR built in your CI stage and configure it.
3. Deploy the configured WAR.

You may find the detail in the [Sharing build artifacts throughout the pipeline](http://www.infoq.com/articles/orch-pipelines-jenkins) from this article.

Comment: Thanks @Hippoom, previously I just mvn package all config files to war, then wrote some script to unzip war, remove unnecessary config files. Maybe the plugin is better way to do it. Also thanks the plugin you suggested, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete the number of possible answers:

You could use the [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to create different deployment war files. From my experience this is much nicer than using ant-tasks for that.